# Navigation and Scrolling PDF file using ng2-pdf-viewer in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to show scroll the PDF file and Navigate PDF file pages using ng2-pdf-viewer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer#page-rendered) in my web application. But it is not working. Navigation is working fine when `[show-all]="false"`.

```
[show-all]="true" [page]="pageNo" [stick-to-page]="true"

<pdf-viewer id="pdfViewerFrame" [src]="statusReportUrl" 
                          [page]="pageNo" [zoom]="zoomValue" (after-load-complete)="callBackFn($event)"
                          [original-size]="true" [autoresize]="false" [fit-to-page]="false" [show-all]="true" [stick-to page]="true"
                        ></pdf-viewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. You can use "ng2-pdfjs-viewer" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer) instead of 
ng2-pdf-viewer.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question you asked

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use "internal link" and you have one by one page, you need to update the current page, using "pagechanging" :

```
<pdf-viewer
(pagechanging)="pagechanging($event)"
[show-all]="false"
[(page)]="page"
 style="display: block; width: 100%;"
>
</pdf-viewer>
```

and in the typescript side:

```
pagechanging(e: CustomEvent){
    this.page = e.pageNumber; // the page variable
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add for pdf-viewer tag style display: block it solve issue for me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `[show-all]="true"` together with `[page]="page"`. show-all is for multiple, scrollable pages. Set `[show-all]="false"` to specify a single page you want to display.

`[stick-to page]="true"` this here should be `[stick-to-page]="true"` and it also is supposed to be used only in a combination with `[show-all]="true"`